# database: aggregation vs storing pre computed data for lookup in large data store?

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, database-performance

We have a table with 2 million records and a new row insertion at 30 records per minute.

The table structure is:
|Complaint | Mobile | RequestDateTime| . We get complain, mobile of user and current date and we save it in this table. We can have multiple rows with same mobile in this table.

We only have to save the new record if we have got less than 12 requests from same "Mobile" in last 30 days. We have three approaches to count number of records with particular mobile here:

1. Every time before inserting new records, first run aggregation query in a database to check if we already have 12 records with that number. If yes, don't insert a new one. The problem here is the performance of the query.
2. OR store this data after day end i.e. rows with the same mobile number in last 29 days in a table and run aggregate only on the current day and add both to check if its less than 12.

OR can someone suggest better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make the argument for checking on the fly...

This is the query, correct?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM tbl
    WHERE num = 1234
      AND datetime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

- You have less than one `INSERT` per second.
- The query should never return more than 12, correct?
- With `INDEX(num, date)`, that `SELECT` is *very* fast.
- Now you are at 60 queries/minute (1/sec).  (One `SELECT` + (usually) one `INSERT`)  Things don't get dicey until over 100/sec.
- BTree indexing is very efficient, and is not affected much by the table size.  So, 2M rows is not a factor.  Nor would 2 billion.
- I suggest that this solution is simpler than the other choices.  KISS.

(I'm a big proponent of Summary Tables, but I can't justify it here.)

Comment: There is a chance that query would return greater than 12 for exitsting records. As initially it was allowed to push as many rows. It could be as high as 200 but after a month, it would be 12

Comment: Add `LIMIT 12` to my suggested query, since you only need to distinguish between "< 12" and ">=12".  (Anyway, 200 would not be too much slower than 12.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. In which cases we should use summary tables I.e. what should be threshold to consider summary table approach when performance is priority

Comment: Here you need to touch only 12 rows to get the answer by brute force.  It it had been, say, 12K, then daily subtotals (in a Summary table) might be wise (then only 30 rows to touch).  Or maybe 120K would be a better threshold; I don't have a real number.  Another consideration:  your 2M rows probably fits in cache (cf `innodb_buffer_pool_size`), so no I/O is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another better way could be :

1) At each EOD, maintain a negative list table of mobile (no of complaints > 12).

2) If record is part of that list, you would never process that. Even you could cache those record in memory (depending on technologies you are using) and avoid DB call all together.

3) Optionally, you could schedule a batch (say every hour), which could update the negative list with additional items and the cache.

**EDIT based on comments**

4) If you do not find a record in negative list table, proceed with your normal logic of counting.

5) You can extend LRU (Least recent used) cache strategy to keep count in-memory for frequent records, to avoid making database call. Make sure to flush a records into negative list as soon as 12 records are inserted in main DB.

Comment: There are couple of issues here 1. If someone bombards database within hour, you will get multiple records from same number 2. At eod, we need to run job on very large dataset I.e every number inserted in last 29 days

Comment: For large dataset case at EOD, If I understand you correctly that you are already counting 29 days data for every record insert during business hours!
Running a one time count during off business hour should not take that time.